# Can an ETH transaction be cancelled?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to create a website where Ethereum transaction can be made.

If I make an Eth transaction using `eth.sendTransaction({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount})` can this transaction be cancelled?

I am asking this because I see that it doesn't take any promise or callback parameters, meaning I would have no idea whether the transaction has been made successfully or not?

Is it possible for web3 transactions to be cancelled? and if it is, how do I make sure that I get notified whether transaction has been made or not? (preferably using promises or callback rather than having to check wallet every time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s *technically* possible to cancel a transaction, but highly unlikely. Essentially, the only way to do so would be to try to send another transaction using the same account/nonce combination and hope it gets mined before the transaction you want to cancel is mined. It’s merely a side effect of how nonce is used to guarantee transaction order rather than a cancellation feature.

For your other question, `web3.eth.sendTransaction` does take a callback. It’s an optional second parameter after the options object and uses the error/result callback style. From the [Web3js API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction):

> `web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject [, callback])`
>
> Function - (optional) If you pass a callback the HTTP request is made asynchronous.
>
> [Using callbacks](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#using-callbacks)
>
> If you want to make an asynchronous request, you can pass an optional callback as the last parameter to most functions. All callbacks are using an error first callback style

Comment: oh yes.. it does. Sorry I don't know why I did not see that. So if the hash is returned, then it is definitely mined and recorded in the blockchain? and it would ALWAYS throw error if for any reason the transaction is 'cancelled'? Thanks.

Comment: The callback is called multiple times. The first callback will be the transaction hash. Once the tx is mined, it will be called again with the transaction receipt. If the tx fails for any reason (including a nonce violation), it will be called with the error set.

Comment: I want to point out that you shouldn’t expect to cancel a transaction. If it’s submitted, expect it to be mined. I was merely pointing out that you could force it to fail, but I wouldn’t recommend it as a part of your process. If you needed to support such a feature, I would build it into the contract itself.

Comment: yes I am not trying to make it fail but I expect it to proceed without failure and to be notified if it happens by slightest chance. but thanks you have provided enough insight for my curiosity

Answer (score 0):

To cancel some ethereum pending transaction you need to:

1. Create a new transaction where you will send 0 ETH to yourselves.
2. You should increase the value of gas fees
3. You need to use the same nonce of the pending transaction.

Using web3js you can do something like this:

```
async function main() {
   require('dotenv').config();
   const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
   const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3");
   const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(API_URL);
   const myAddress = //put your address
   const nonce = //put the nonce of pending tx
   const maxFeePerGas = //increase the gas fee value comparated to the pending tx 

   const transaction = {
      'to': myAddress,
      'value': 0,
      'gas': 21000,
      'maxFeePerGas': maxFeePerGas,
      'nonce': nonce
   };

   const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transaction, PRIVATE_KEY);

   web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction, function(error, hash) {
      if (!error) {
         console.log("The hash of your transaction is: ", hash);
      } else {
         console.log(error)
      }
    });
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target - cancel, all pending transactions (nonce - one by one) using e.g.  Metamask/Settings/Advanced/"Customize transaction nonce", with the higher maxFeePerGas and maxPriorityFeePerGas - front runned (validated first):

0. Choose alternative Ethereum RPC Server Address - this sometimes help:
   https://chainlist.org/chain/1
1. Use the same (pending transactions') nonce!

### THIS SHOULD BE ENOUGH

Destination address could be the source address.
ETH amount could be 0.

You can even tray to send Raw Transaction (e.g. using MyCrypto), something like:

{"to":"0x____","from":"0x____","data":"0x","maxFeePerGas":"0x____","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"0x____","type":2,"value":"0x____","nonce":"0x____","gasLimit":"0x____","chainId":1}